# sqs.sendMessage not getting delivered

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have this very simple lambda that sends a message to a queue:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2'});
    var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
    await sqs.sendMessage({
        // DelaySeconds: 2*5,
        MessageBody: 'Test message!',
        QueueUrl: 'https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/9999999999/TestQueue'
    });
};
```

However, I find that the number of messages in the queue is always zero (I've confirmed this from CloudWatch metrics also).

The original goal was to send a delayed message, but for now, I'm stuck with getting the simplest version to work. The role the lambda has provides all the necessary permissions, and the function executes normally when invoked.

What are the possible reasons for this behavior?

Comment: Check your Lambda logs. Is there an error when attempting to write to SQS? Check the permissions on your Lambda execution role. Can it write to that queue?

Comment: You should also try setting up the optional callback function in `sendMessage`. It will allow you to catch any error that is occurring like so: `sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
  }
});`

Comment: @bpgeck No, there are no errors, and yes, the lambda has the necessary permissions (full SQS access, for that matter). I don't get an error but I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @bpgeck I figured it out finally. We have to use `sqs.sendMessage().promise()` here as the aws-sdk functions aren't promisified by default. :|

Comment: @bpgeck you should add your conclusion as an answer. The same happened to me. Thanks for your comment!!

Answer (score 0):

Copying conclusion in answer from comments given by @ankush981

Use following method to solve the issue:

`sqs.sendMessage().promise()`

Comment: Just want to add that this is a very common pattern in the AWS docs. If you see a callback function, tacking on a `.promise()` at its end has a high chance of letting you use `await` even if the docs don't mention it. :-)